# Is it fine to use sessionStorage instead of shared service

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, session-storage

I would just like to know if it is bad to use sessionStorage instead of a sharedservice in Angular. The reason why is just because sessionStorage is so easy:

- I can easily access it from anywhere in my app
- I don't need to worry about importing it everywhere
- I don't need to worry about circular injection issues

sessionStorage is just so easy to use that I would love to use it to store stuff like the current logged in user, user access, base URL for calls...everything I would put in a sharedservice

Comment: Not good practice?

Comment: well, Safari private mode doesn't have local/session Storage. I believe `sessionStorage` is for one browser tab only. Services are easy to work with, and if you worry you will lose some data after a page refresh, then that data should probably be saved in your database

Answer (score 1):

you can use `sessionStorage` everywhere in your app but it is not the best way to solve the problem. Just imagine if in the future you want to switch to a different storage mechanism, like [store.js](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js/) for example, are you going to change all the references in your app with the new library?

It's easier and much flexible if you create a tiny wrapper around the storage mechanism that will just invoke the library transparently from the caller.

something like:

```
angular.service('Storage', function() {

  this.set = (key, value) => {
    storageMechanism.set(key, value);
  };

  this.get = key => {
    return storageMechanism.get(key);
  };

});
```